# android - some views are not "visible" after activity restart

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

Hello Android developers,

i'm facing a strange behaviour of some views after activity restart - there are some views, which are not "visible", but they are layouted and react on Touch actions.

I'm trying to keep the application follow Android lifetime guide. I drop the Activity to background and let system to close my activity. Then I navigate back to my activity, which is recreated. There is no problem with data to be corrupted (saved in db with every change made), but the views are. There are some properly shown, but everything inside **TableView**, which is inside **ScrollView**, is not visible. If I call **getVisibility()** on any of not shown views, i get that it is visible. As I mentioned above, views are not "visible", but react on Touch and scroll events, like they were properly shown.

This is also hard (impossible) to debug, cause when the app is closed, debbuger is disconnected. But anyway, recreation follows the same methods callback - **onCreate()**, **onStart()**, **onResume()**, so once created, why there's problem other time? The only difference to me is that there is a **null Bundle** in **onCreate(Bundle)** when Activity is newly created and **not null** when it is recreated by system. If the activity is only stopped (in background) but not closed by system, everything works fine.

I also tryed to override **onSaveInstanceState()** and **onRestoreInstanceState()** with nothing to be saved and restored (no call to super implementation), but it had no effect.

I'm using Android 4.1.1 and emulator 2.1.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks Ales

Here are (links to) screenshots to figure it out better:
[Before activity is closed by system](http://alesrazym.cz/tmp/eliz_001.png)
[After activity is recreated](http://alesrazym.cz/tmp/eliz_002.png)

Here are the layout files:

```
    <!-- Header --> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startlistHeaderLayout" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textStartlistName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text=""
            />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textStarttime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Results --> 
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@id/resultsScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@id/timingLapTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:shrinkColumns="2"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            >
            <!-- rows are added in code -->
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- R.layout.timing_row -->
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/timingTableRow"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textTimingPosition"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textTimingBib"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="1dip"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textTimingName"
        android:text=""
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="1dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textTimingBehind1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textTimingBehind2"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        />
</TableRow>
```

Here is part of Activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    loadPreferencesTimingTheme();
    if (ownTheme) {
        this.setTheme(theme);
    } else {
        this.setTheme(MainActivity.theme);
    }
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View lapView;
    View v;
    int sid;
    setContentView(R.layout.startlist_edit);
    sid = getIntent().getIntExtra(TimingActivity.STARTLIST_ID, -1);
    if (sid == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, could not load startlist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        this.finish();
        return;
    }
    tdb = new TimingDB(this);
    sl = tdb.getStartlist(sid); // get Startlist from db into memory
    // hide unnecessary columns
    v = findViewById(R.id.timingLapTableLayout);
    ((TableLayout) v).setColumnCollapsed(0, true);
    loadStartlist(sl); // inflate rows with startlist data and set listeners
    // load the preferences and set preferences listener
    loadPreferences();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsChangeListener);
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsChangeListener);
    if (tdb != null) tdb.close();
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (tdb != null) tdb.close();
}

private void loadStartlist(StartList sl) {
    // set startlist name & time
    View v = findViewById(R.id.textStarttime);
    ((TextView) v).setText(SimpleDateFormats.ddmmyyyyhhmmss.format(new Date(sl.getStartTime())));
    v = findViewById(R.id.textStartlistName);
    ((TextView) v).setText(sl.getName());
    // set header onclicklistener
    v = findViewById(R.id.startlistHeaderLayout);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // show dialog to change startlist name and time
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(KEY_NAME, ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStartlistName)).getText().toString());
            args.putString(KEY_STTIME, ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textStarttime)).getText().toString());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
                dialogBundle = args;
                showDialog(DIALOG_EDIT_STARTLIST);
            } else {
                showDialog(DIALOG_EDIT_STARTLIST, args);
            }
        }
    });
    // add competitors to startlist
    int cnt = sl.getCompetitorsCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        Competitor c = sl.getCompetitorByIndex(i);
        appendStartlistRow(c);
    }
}

public void appendStartlistRow(final Competitor c) {
    TableRow inflatedView = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.timing_row, null);
    inflatedView.setTag(TAG_COMPETITOR, c);
    inflatedView.setTag(new Integer(c.getBib()));
    inflatedView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.timingLapTableLayout);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(KEY_INDEX, tl.indexOfChild(v));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
                dialogBundle = args;
                showDialog(DIALOG_EDIT_COMPETITOR);
            } else {
                showDialog(DIALOG_EDIT_COMPETITOR, args);
            }
        }
    });
    // set up texts
    TextView text = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textTimingBib);
    text.setText(c.getBib() + "");
    text = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textTimingName);
    text.setText(c.getName());
    text = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textTimingBehind1);
    text.setText(getFormatedStartTime(sl, c, Settings.STARTTIME_ABSOLUTE));
    text = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textTimingBehind2);
    text.setText(getFormatedStartTime(sl, c, Settings.STARTTIME_RELATIVE));
    // append the row
    appendStartlistRow((ViewGroup) inflatedView);
}

public void appendStartlistRow(ViewGroup row) {
    // set background and text colors
    if (((((Integer) row.getTag()).intValue()) % 2) == Defs.VIEW_EVEN) {
        row.setBackgroundColor(Defs.COLOR_BACKGROUND_EVEN);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++) {
            ((TextView) (row.getChildAt(j))).setTextColor(Defs.COLOR_TEXT_EVEN);
        }
    } else {
        row.setBackgroundColor(Defs.COLOR_BACKGROUND_ODD);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++) {
            ((TextView) (row.getChildAt(j))).setTextColor(Defs.COLOR_TEXT_ODD);
        }
    }
    ((TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.timingLapTableLayout)).addView(row);
}
```

Defs.java:

```
public class Defs {
    protected static final int VIEW_EVEN = 0;
    protected static final int VIEW_ODD = 1;
    protected static int COLOR_BACKGROUND_EVEN;
    protected static int COLOR_BACKGROUND_ODD;
    protected static int COLOR_BACKGROUND_SELECTED;
    protected static int COLOR_BACKGROUND_SPYED;
    protected static int COLOR_TEXT_ODD;
    protected static int COLOR_TEXT_EVEN;
    protected static int COLOR_TEXT_SELECTED;
    protected static int COLOR_TEXT_SPYED;

    private static boolean isInitialized = false;

    protected static void init(Context c) {
        if (isInitialized) return;
        COLOR_BACKGROUND_EVEN = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.background_darker);
        COLOR_BACKGROUND_ODD = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.background_lighter);
        COLOR_BACKGROUND_SELECTED = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.background_selected);
        COLOR_BACKGROUND_SPYED = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.background_spyed);
        COLOR_TEXT_ODD = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_lighter);
        COLOR_TEXT_EVEN = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_darker);
        COLOR_TEXT_SELECTED = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_selected);
        COLOR_TEXT_SPYED = c.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_spyed);
        isInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've post the code (to make the question and answer complete) and meanwhile found the bug - there is a Defs class i'm using to hold the text and background colors. Because it needs to be initialized with Context to get resources, I call the init() from the main activity, but then, when this activity is recreated, Defs are not initialized. So calling the Defs.init() in onCreate() fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's next to impossible to say much about the problem itself. But I did want to say (would fit better as a comment but can't do it yet) that for a long list (like yours seems to be based on the screenshots) using an actual `ListView` with a custom `ArrayAdapter` might be a better solution. `ListView` re-uses views when scrolled thus reducing unnecessary view creation. Also, once you learn how to use the `ListView`, you'll probably find it easier than adding table rows manually. If those aren't familiar to you, check a tutorial here:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

And if you decide to change from tables to a `ListView`, maybe the problem (whatever it is) disappears as well. You never know. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for tips. I've already thought of `LinearLayout` instead. I use `ListView` with Adapter in other part of application, but here I expect heavy scrolling, so I decided to load everything into memory. Maybe I missed some point of view, but I expect `ListView` to work better with items like pictures scrolled from time to time. And application works smoothly on low-end device(s) this way. As I'm not an expert, this is just my opinion..